# Change NetGear SSID

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am not a "*systems guy*" and am setting up a home network for the very first time. I am using a wireless NetGear WNR2000v2 router.

When I go into the router config page (192.168.1.1) I see the section where I can name my SSID. The default value is `NETGEAR`. I would like to change that to something else, like `zacs-sandbox`, however I have one hang-up that is preventing me from taking the next step.

I have a desktop running Ubuntu that does not have a wireless card and I am intentionally keeping it that way. I am connecting that machine to my router via Cat(5?) cable. When I do this, the only network I see available to connect to is `Auto eth0`, which I can see is provided by my router. I know this because I can only access the router config page from that machine when it's connected to the router.

**My question**: I understand the term *SSID* to be the name of the WLAN, which would be the wireless network I am broadcasting from that router. But if I change the name of my router's SSID to, say, `zacs-sandbox`, I don't think my wired Ubuntu desktop will show the reflected change from `Auto eth0` to `zacs-sandbox`.

What do I need to do to change `Auto eth0` to the same name as my SSID?

Comment: Does the router have a section where it says "domain" or "internal network name"? If so, it'll probably be set as "internal" or something similar. See if you can find that and change that to the SSID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router actually consists of two parts - the router that provides your internet connection and an attached wireless access point that provides the wireless features. Changing the Broadcast SSID of the access point will not affect the router's ethernet information so your wired computer won't even know there has been a change.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the SSID only affects what's broadcast over wireless; it'll have no effect on wired connections.

Comment: Sure, so how do I change the name of my wired connection?

Comment: Actually on some Netgear routers the name network of wired connection will change on Windows.

Comment: Steve - I appreciate your answer and would be happy to give you the green check but the core of my question was really about how to get my wired connection and SSID to be in synch with one another. Any ideas?

Comment: @zharvey - What is the purpose of changing the wired connection.  Only computers using a CAT 5/6 cable will see the connection.